# Controlling the haptic device (Phantom Omni) position

Tags: c++

I have a Phantom Omni device and given any position co-ordinates, how to move the device stylus to that position? Is there a direct command in Open Haptics for that?

Comment: I don't really know the API, but it would really surprise me if such a command existed. An imedance haptic device (such as the PHANToM) is controlled by force. It's a non-trivial task to compute the force required to reach a point, especially since you'd need to know how fast you want to reach it.

Comment: so the idea behind moving the stylus is to minimize the difference between current position and the new position right? Or is it something more than that?

Comment: Mathematically, you'd express the stylus position as a function of time (e.g., the position you want after 0.1s, 0.2s etc.), differentiate twice to get the acceleration necessary for this motion, and compute the force from this acceleration and mechanical properties of the device (weight, friction). I can't see a more direct way, but I am not a haptics expert.

Comment: If you have feedback on its position you could design a control loop (PID) to get you to a desired position.